# Javascript: extend classes with undefined class

Tags: javascript, browser

Consider the following two files:

```
/* file A.js */
class A extends B {

}

/* file B.js */
class B {

}
```

If I accidentaly load these two files into the browser in the inverse order (`A.js` first then `B.js`) javascript will throw an error, that I am trying to access `B` that is undefined.

My problem is, that I have to deal with around 30-40 classes defined in Javascript, and right now, for all of them to work, I have to keep in mind the order in which I want to include them in the page, or otherwise, javascript will throw an error that I am using something that is undefined.

How could I resolve this issue, so I don't have to constantly keep in mind the order in which these classes are loaded into the web page?

Comment: *I have to deal with around 30-40 classes* Too disorganized for decent code IMO, consider setting up a module system instead, like with Webpack

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am combining these files when we are going to production with something, but even with Webpack, I would need to know the order in which to bundle all of my files, do I not?

Comment: @AdamBaranyai - Nope, not if you're using modules. :-) You just express the dependencies of the module within the module. Then Webpack (or similar) builds the dependency tree for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd resolve it by using modules. Modules declare their dependencies explicitly and you only have to reference the top-level module in the page; the rest will be loaded according to the dependency tree. So for instance, `B.js` would be:

```
export class B {
    // ...
}
```

Then `A.js` would be:

```
import { B } from "./B.js";
export class A extends B {
    // ...
}
```

Perhaps your main entry point (`main.js` or whatever) would have:

```
import { A } from "./A.js";
// ...
```

Then your page has

```
<script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
```

...and the other dependencies are loaded as needed.

This works with native module support in browsers, and/or if you use a bundler like Rollup.js, Webpack, ...

Comment: I was considering modules, but based on `caniuse.com` data, modules are only supported by ~85% of the globally used browsers. I think loosing 15% of potential clients is a big concern. I started reading about `Webpack` based on the previous comment to my question, am I correct in assuming, that webpack will remove these `modules` from the files, and create a standard javascript file that is module less, so I can keep my browser support?

Comment: @AdamBaranyai - Right. Webpack and other bundlers can create bundles that don't rely on native module support in browsers. That's what I meant by "native module support..and/or if you use a bundler."

Comment: maybe you could give me a hint on my follow up question to this also?:) https://stackoverflow.com/q/59919176/2691879