# Manual testing with webpack modules

Tags: javascript, webpack

This is a follow up question for my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59918447/2691879):

Basically, webpack would solve the issue I am having in the previous question, but I can't figure out a good way to be able to manually test my pages javascript files.

When I first read what webpack does, I was planning to do the following:

1. write my code with imports with a single entry point, using `npm` dependencies.
2. while testing out my code, in `developement` version, I would load the main module file into the browser, for testing purposes, which would import the dependencies (this is where I am having a problem)
3. for production version, I would bundle everything with `webpack`, so browsers that are not supporting the `import` statement can still run my javascript

The obvious problem with this (at least the obvious one to me), is that if I do something like this in my javascript file:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
```

the browser will have no idea what does `'jquery'` stand for, while node will handle this quite well.

**OPTION** An option would be, to always bundle my files with `webpack`, even for developement version but this would lead to two problems imo:

1. it would get very tedious, without an automated tool: whenever I modify one of my .js files, I would need to run the bundler again. I could find a solution for this issue, there is maybe an automated watch tool, or if not, I could write one.
2. when I will then manually test my code, if there are errors in it, it will be very hard to find and match the error the browser throws, to my actual, unbundled code.

Isn't there a tool, or a method, with which I can use npm modules loaded from a browser, that would resolve the imports just like node does, so that I can follow my initial three step plan for working with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use webpack for debugging your application in development environment. Webpack provided a watcher to re-bundle your source code at any change, from memory the command is `--inline hot`. For your second problem search about `sourceMap` webpack provided you an access to your source code whenever it is bundled.

https://ehsangazar.com/source-maps-and-how-it-works-b3f93ca7ea5 => article about webpack sourcemap

Comment: Source maps indeed does the trick, if I always precompile. Is there any way to test unbundled in developement?

Comment: I never test my application unbundled in development environment, but you can probably create an another entrypoint for your application like `index-unbundled.js` which take care of require all your dependencies, tedious work but it should work